# Word for dreamer

Tags: phrases

Is there a word or phrase that describes a person or the act of dreaming of all the good a person will do if they won the lottery.

There are words Dreamer or fantasiser, but I was looking for phrase that might decribe this particular type of dream as this dream might become possible if the lottery is won.

Of course the reality of winning the lottery might raise a whole new set of problems. Then there is the gap between the dream and reality.

The person would be daydreaming.

Comment: What's wrong with "dreamer"? What's wrong with all the synonyms listed in the thesaurus for "dreamer"? Please edit to address these questions and also add an example sentence where you would use the word/phrase, as is required.

Comment: Do you mean a person who is physically asleep, or a person who is fantasizing while awake (ie “daydreaming”)?

Comment: Is it the “person of activity” (presumably an *active person*, or else an *or/of* typo) doing the dreaming?

Comment: There's the expression "building castles in the sky", though it might be more dismissive than you intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would characterize it as "a transcendent dream." Transcendent: "surpassing the ordinary." New Oxford American Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody who is pondering what they would do if they won the lottery, perhaps planning things out on a provisional basis, is someone who is **speculating**:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> *intransitive*
> **1 a** : to meditate on or ponder a subject : REFLECT
>
> *intransitive*
> **1** : to take to be true on the basis of insufficient evidence : THEORIZE
>
> **2** : to be curious or doubtful about : WONDER
> // *speculates* whether it will rain all vacation

In noun form, the person would be a *speculator*.